# Convention to add code while answering in middle of text

Tags: support, code-formatting

While answering the questions I need to add code in middle of the text, but after selecting the code in editor still it doesn't reflect as a code. It suggests me to give spaces.

So suggest what convention should be followed to add code in answers.

Comment: give spaces?... The suggestion is telling you exactly what to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it is quite easy to include some code, like `while(true) { }`, in the middle of an answer. Just use 'backticks':

```
`while(true) { }`
```

The (four) spaces are to mark an entire block of text as code, just like the block above. For more information, see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - you can also [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/325730/edit) someones post to see how it was formatted.